# An two-norm estimate for symmetric $k$-tensors

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

Let $(V, \langle, \rangle)$ be an $n$ dimensional innerproduct space and let $S^k(V)$ denote the space of $k$-fold symmetric tensors.  The inner product naturally extends to $S^k(V)$.  Denote the associated norms by $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$.

Let $S_1^k(V)=\{v\otimes\cdots \otimes v: v\in V, \}\subset $ be the set of rank one symmetric $k$-tensors.  One can show that $S^k(V)=\mathrm{span}(S_1^k(V))$.

For $S\in S^k(V)$, set
$$
\Vert S \Vert_*= \inf\{ \Vert S_1\Vert_2+\ldots+\Vert S_r \Vert_2: S=\sum_{i=1}^r  S_i, S_i\in S_1^k(V)\}.
$$
Clearly, $\Vert \cdot \Vert_*$ is a norm on $S^k(V)$.

It's immediate that, when $k=1$, $\Vert S\Vert_2=\Vert S\Vert_*$.  When $k=2$, you can use the spectral theorem to see that $\Vert S\Vert_*\leq \sqrt{rank(S)}\Vert S\Vert_2\leq \sqrt{n} \Vert S\Vert_2$.

My question is whether the bound $\Vert S\Vert_*\leq C(n) \Vert S\Vert_2$ continues to hold for $k\geq 3$.  Or if there is at least a bound
$$
\Vert S\Vert_* \leq C(n,k) \Vert S\Vert_2
$$
for some reasonably explicit $C(n,k)\geq 1$.

Comment: This may be me being stupid, but I don't get your definition of $\|S\|_*$. If $S_1$ is one of the rank-one summands, why can't you replace the decomposition of $S$ with $(1/m)S_1 + \dotsb + (1/m)S_1$, which in the expression for $\|S\|_*$ replaces $\|S_1\|_2^2$ with $m \|(1/m)S_1\|_2^2 = (1/m)\|S_1\|_2^2$? As $m\to \infty$ this $\to 0$. Do you want to add some condition like the summands $S_i$ are linearly independent, or $r$ is minimal?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Good point.  I changed the definition to account for this (and to be consistent with the definition of the norm of the sum of spaces).  I think this deals with your issue.

Comment: Now $\|S\|_*$ is called the *nuclear norm* of $S$, see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3860. I don't know if that helps directly but perhaps searching for "nuclear norm" might turn up something helpful. Good luck.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thank you that is very helpful.